# Wait until page is loaded when using XMLHTTP approach

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, youtube, xmlhttprequest

In the following working code, I am trying to navigate to specific youtube channel
To get the videos names into excel ..
It is working but partially as the code just lists about 30 videos only

```
    Dim x, html As Object, ele As Object, sKeyWords As String, i As Long

With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "youtube channel url videos", False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send

    If .Status <> 200 Then MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & .Status & " - " & .statusText: Exit Sub

    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
```

How can I maje the code load all the content of the page ..? so as to get all the videos that are listed there.

I have found a site that lists all the videos in one table but as for the part of scraping the table, I failed to extract the video name or even dealing with the table
Here's my try

```
Sub Post_Method()
Dim http        As New XMLHTTP60
Dim html        As New HTMLDocument
Dim htmla       As Object
Dim trow        As Object
Dim tcel        As Object
Dim strArg      As String
Dim c           As Long
Dim x           As Long

strArg = "inputType=1&stringInput=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fchannel%2FUC43lrLHl4EhxaKQn2HrcJPQ&limit=100&keyType=default&customKey="

With http
    .Open "POST", "https://youtube-playlist-analyzer.appspot.com/submit", False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send strArg
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
   ' WriteTxtFile html.body.innerHTML
End With

Dim posts As Object, elem As Object, r As Long

'This part I can't adjust
'------------------------
    Set posts = html.getElementById("container").getElementById("tableContainer").getElementById("tableData")

    For Each elem In posts.Children
        For Each trow In elem.Cells
            c = c + 1: Cells(r + 1, c) = trow.innerText
        Next trow
        c = 0: r = r + 1
    Next elem
    '----------------------------------
 Stop

End Sub
```

Comment: you realise with YouTube frequently a lot of the content is dynamically loaded as you scroll the page - have you checked whether that is a factor?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have noticed that. So I asked this question, may be there is a workaround to make the page fully loaded ...

Comment: My intuition would be that selenium and slow scroll is likely best approach but I haven’t tested.

Comment: Thank you. Can you guide me to how use scroll in selenium ..?

Comment: There should be examples on SO especially in python tag. Slow scroll until no more results. User alexce wrote a well known answer on this - I recognise not so helpful unless you can read python. User sim has probably written an equivalent in vba selenium on here or code review.

Comment: I have found another website that may help me. I have updated the question and put my try. I need some help at scraping the table. Just two pieces : video name and views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use that endpoint then extract the javascript object from the response which contains data of interest and parse with jsonconverter.bas.

**Json library:**

I use jsonconverter.bas. Download raw code from [here](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) and add to standard module called JsonConverter . You then need to go VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime. Remove the top Attribute line from the copied code.

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetYouTubeViews()

    Dim s As String, ws As Worksheet, body As String

    body = "inputType=1&stringInput=https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC43lrLHl4EhxaKQn2HrcJPQ&limit=100&keyType=default"

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", "https://youtube-playlist-analyzer.appspot.com/submit", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send body
        s = .responseText
    End With

    Dim results(), r As Long, jsonSource As String
    Dim json As Object, item As Object, headers()

    jsonSource = GetString(s, "json_items = ", ";")

    If jsonSource = "No match" Then Exit Sub

    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonSource)

    headers = Array("Title", "ViewCount")

    ReDim results(1 To json.Count, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)

    For Each item In json
        r = r + 1
        results(r, 1) = item("title")
        results(r, 2) = item("viewCount")
    Next

    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetString(ByVal inputString As String, ByVal startPhrase As String, ByVal endPhrase As String) As String
    Dim s As Long, e As Long

    s = InStr(inputString, startPhrase)
    If Not s > 0 Then
        GetString = "No match"
        Exit Function
    End If

    e = InStr(s + Len(startPhrase) - 1, inputString, endPhrase)

    If Not e > 0 Then
        GetString = "No match"
        Exit Function
    End If
    GetString = Mid$(inputString, s + Len(startPhrase), e - (s + Len(startPhrase)))
End Function
```

---

**Sample results:**

[image]

---

**Py:**

A lot more concise with python

```
import requests, re, json ,csv

data = {
  'inputType': '1',
  'stringInput': 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC43lrLHl4EhxaKQn2HrcJPQ',
  'limit': '100',
  'keyType': 'default'
}

r = requests.post('https://youtube-playlist-analyzer.appspot.com/submit',  data=data)
p = re.compile(r'json_items = (.*?);', re.DOTALL)
results = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])

with open("data.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as csv_file:
    w = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL) #change this for locale
    w.writerow(['Title','ViewCount'])
    for item in results:
        w.writerow([item['title'], item['viewCount']])
```

Comment: That's awesome. Really awesome. Thank you very much
As for the part of scraping table what's the problem exactly as I couldn't deal with it at all ...?

Comment: The table I think is constructed dynamically from JavaScript instructions in the response. If that is the case it would require a browser to populate the table.

Comment: sorry for disturbing you .. I got an error `run-time error 10001. Error parsing JSON 5\n2. Alt Expecting '" or "` at this line of JSONConverter `Err.Raise 10001, "JSONConverter", json_ParseErrorMessage(json_String, json_Index, "Expecting '""' or '''")` ... The error happens with this URL `https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKpSyGzIQhX0IXLNNJhf76g`

Comment: Have you examined the response?

Comment: The error occurred at the JSONConverter module and I totally feel lost at it .. can you try the channel url I posted in the previous comment?

Comment: you need to print the response rather than let it get to jsonconverter. And yes, I will have a look later today.

Comment: I have exported the response to html document and it seems very good. The error just happened when trying to parse JSON

Comment: i will look later

Comment: I have discovered the cause. There is a video with a description that has semi-colon so I changed this line `jsonSource = GetString(s, "json_items = ", ";" & vbLf & vbLf)` and it works well now