# VBA Regex Single Line Flag

Tags: regex, vba

In my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58249728/wait-until-page-is-loaded-when-using-xmlhttp-approach/58251008#58251008) SO question I originally tried using regex to grab the javascript array that follows `json_items =` and ends lazily at first `";"` i.e. captures everything in the javascript array `[array]`  variable called `json_items`.

You can see the start of the match here:

[image]

And the regex is saved [here](https://regex101.com/r/ICV6fb/3/). I can correctly match with `json_items = (.*?);` in both python and PCRE (PHP) if I set the `re.DOTALL` flag or single line flag respectively.

For example, in Python the following functions correctly:

```
import requests, re, json

data = {
  'inputType': '1',
  'stringInput': 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC43lrLHl4EhxaKQn2HrcJPQ',
  'limit': '100',
  'keyType': 'default'
}

r = requests.post('https://youtube-playlist-analyzer.appspot.com/submit',  data=data)
p = re.compile(r'json_items = (.*?);', re.DOTALL)
results = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
```

The array is retrieved. However, I cannot seem to find the right setting (or to adjust regex appropriately) to do the same in VBA. My best attempt is shown below. It simply fails to match. How do I grab the javascript array as discussed using Regex in VBA please?

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub RegexMatch()

    Dim s As String, ws As Worksheet, body As String, re As Object

    body = "inputType=1&stringInput=https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC43lrLHl4EhxaKQn2HrcJPQ&limit=100&keyType=default"

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", "https://youtube-playlist-analyzer.appspot.com/submit", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send body
        s = .responseText
    End With

    Dim matches As Object

    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .pattern = "json_items = (.*?);"
        If .Test(s) Then
            Set matches = .Execute(s)
            Debug.Print matches(0).SubMatches(0)
        Else
           Debug.Print "Failed"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---

To preserve two answers given in comments:

FlorentB:

```
var json_items\s*=\s*((?:"(?:\\"|[^"])+"|[^;"]+)+)
```

Wiktor Stribiżew:

```
There is no option, use [^] or [\s\S] / [\d\D] / [\w\W] instead of a dot.
```

Comment: There is no option, use `[^]` or `[\s\S]` / `[\d\D]` / `[\w\W]` instead of a dot.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. I tried .pattern = "json_items = ([\s\S] / [\d\D] / [\w\W]*?);"  but that fails. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: Oh... but you mean .pattern = "json_items = ([\s\S]*?);"  ?

Comment: A `.` does not match line break chars, do not use it if you need to match any char.

Comment: Use `var json_items\s*=\s*((?:"(?:\\"|[^"])+"|[^;"]+)+)` to match the JSON. It matches all the characters until `;` and ignores the quoted ones.